# Why VSCode asks me to choose a repo when I try to commit git?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why VSCode asks me to choose a repo when I try to commit git?

When I press the "commit all changes" command, VSCode shows this:

[image]

`prolife-cms` is the project I'm working on

`prolife-store` is a project I'm not working on, I don't even open any files about from that project, why VSCode asks me about it? I just want to commit whatever in the project I'm working on.

Comment: What remotes you have linked to that project folder? (what's the output of `git remote -v`?)

Comment: Do you have nested repositories or submodules?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't have nested repo. But what do you mean anyway?

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta just one remote. the out is the repo link I'm working on

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when working on a multi repo workspace, enabling *"Always Show Repositories"* under VSCode settings solved this.

Steps:

1. Go to **File > Preferences > Settings** (or **Code > Preferences > Settings** for macOS)
2. Go to **User > Features > SCM**
3. Check/Turn on the option **"Always Show Repositories"**

[image]